# Error with exporting Excel file from Database (vb.net)

Tags: mysql, vb.net

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class
> factory for component with CLSID
> {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
> error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'

I was just trying to export a `Database` using vb.net to an `Excel file`, I have tried to install and reinstall microsoft excel, adding and readding the imports of microsoft. can someone please helpppp

code:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

        Dim cnn As SqlConnection
        Dim cnnst As String
        Dim sql As String
        Dim i, j As Integer
        Dim xlapp As New Excel.Application
        Dim xlworkbook As New Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlworksheet As New Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misvalue As Object = Reflection.Missing.Value
        xlapp = New Excel.Application
        xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add(misvalue)
        xlworksheet = xlworkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
        cnnst = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=myconnector"
        cnn = New SqlConnection(cnnst)
        cnn.Open()
        sql = "select * from attendance"
        Dim cmd As New SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        cmd.Fill(ds)
        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                xlworksheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(j)
            Next
        Next

        xlworksheet.SaveAs("D:\Report.xlsx")
        xlworkbook.Close()
        xlapp.Quit()
        Myobject(xlapp)
        Myobject(xlworkbook)
        Myobject(xlworksheet)
        cnn.Close()
        MsgBox("success", "Exported", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} is the WorkBook Class.

Do not try to instantiate a Workbook by using the `New` keyword in the variable declaration statement.

```
Dim xlworkbook As New Excel.Workbook
```

should be

```
Dim xlworkbook As Excel.Workbook
```

The same also applies to the Worksheet variable declaration.

Comment: yeah it still does that

Comment: xlworkbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add(misvalue) this is the code thats getting the error